# How to make absolute textbox positioned in the middle of each row?

Tags: html, css

I have a simpe table table. There are hidden textbox inside each cells. When I double click the cell, the specific textbox on current cell should show up. The textbox position should be in front of the table, absolute position an in the center of each row. This is the td of my table:

```
<td class="live_column">
   <input type="hidden" class="h_textbox" name="bidang_job" value="EDIT HERE" style="position:absolute; margin-left:auto; width:80%;" />
</td>
```

My current table show up like this:
[image]

I can make it happen by using `margin-left:-x px`.
For example:

- In row 1, all the textbox position have `margin-left:0px`
- In row 2, `margin-left:-250px`
- In row 3, `margin-left:-500px`

I don't know if that's the proper way. By the way, here's the desired output:
[image]

Comment: Why do you increase the margin-left for each textbox if you want them all to be aligned?

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin Well, I haven't found a way to make the textbox aligned. so, I use that.

Comment: Please show us your code. We will correct it for you.

Comment: The code is in the textboxt . There's a style there.

Answer (score 0):

The align attribute of  is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.

Specifies the alignment of an image input (only for type="image"). Only the "left" and "right" values of the align attribute work properly in all major browsers.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to position the textbox relative to the `<tr>`. Something like this:

```
table tr {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

td.live_column .h_textbox {
  position: absolute;

  /* Align it to the horizontal and vertical center of the row */
  left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```css
/* Positioning the textboxes to the center */
table tr {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
td.live_column .h_textbox {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; top: 0;
  margin: auto;
}


/* Some style to format the boxes */
td {
  border: 2px #666 solid;
  height: 40px;
  width: 90px;
}

td.live_column .h_textbox {
  height: 16px;
  width: 80%;
  border: 2px #F05 solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="live_column">
      <input type="text" class="h_textbox" name="bidang_job" value="EDIT HERE" />
    </td>
    <td></td> <td></td> <td></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="live_column">
      <input type="text" class="h_textbox" name="bidang_job" value="EDIT HERE" />
    </td>
    <td></td> <td></td> <td></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="live_column">
      <input type="text" class="h_textbox" name="bidang_job" value="EDIT HERE" />
    </td>
    <td></td> <td></td> <td></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: it seem has conflict with bootstrap table style

Comment: If that is the case, you can prioritize this style by adding classes to your tables/TRs, and add the relevant style on that `table.your_table tr.your_tr`.